# Restricting OpenVPN connection to only one program

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, vpn, openvpn

My Linux server works with YouTube videos a lot, downloading and collecting data about them with the help of `youtube-dl`.

I want to route this program (`youtube-dl`) through an OpenVPN connection. Seems simple enough, except I need *only* `youtube-dl` to use the VPN connection, as I also run a web server among other things which **cannot** use the VPN connection.

How can I configure my server to only use the OpenVPN connection for `youtube-dl`?

**Without a separate VM.**

Comment: Is Docker out of question, too?

Comment: On the networking / routing level your options are either:

Policy routing (when you know exactly which IP’s are used by your app to download videos from) 

Network name spaces (which is a pita to set up manually)

Comment: @HermanB Policy routing isn't really feasible, as sometimes `youtube-dl` will also fetch media from other arbitrary sources. Let me look more into network namespaces, thanks!

Comment: You can look at `firejail`, despite its name it can work with other programs than Firefox, and "enclose" them in various limits, including a networking namespace which should be the ideal option for your problem. See https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/basic-usage/#networking

Comment: Can you explain how this could be useful, as U-tube probably isn't part of your VPN?

Comment: Run web server in a VM instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot I asked this question, but I may as well leave the solution I ended up using here:

You can use a program called [Vopono](https://github.com/jamesmcm/vopono) that works by creating temporary network namespaces.

It supports the Wireguard, OpenVPN, OpenConnect and OpenFortiVPN protocols, and can also be used out-of-the-box directly with many VPNs such as PIA and NordVPN as well, if that suits your needs.

Example usage with an OpenVPN configuration file:

```
vopono exec --custom vpn_config.ovpn --protocol openvpn "youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
```

## No VM or anything like that needed!

More detailed usage info can be found [here](https://github.com/jamesmcm/vopono/blob/master/USERGUIDE.md).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual machine that connects to the VPN and run the program in that VM.

Comment: apparently, this was answered before the additional requirement appeared, and for majority of cases this is acceptable solution